# Diff directory contents from Mac to PC on same network

Tags: windows, mac, ssh, rsync, scp

I have a Mac and a PC on the same LAN. The PC is running OpenSSH.

I copied a folder of (subfolders containing) 30 GB of files from the Mac to PC via:
`scp -r ~/orig_folder/* my_user@192.168.1.106:another_folder/`

I'm hesitating to delete the 30 GB of files from the Mac before doing some kind of "diff" (comparison) to prove that all of the files successfully copied to the PC.

I've heard of `rsync` but think it doesn't work from Mac to Windows, right? (I tried a lot of different `rsync` SSH commands.)

If also tried simpler approaches of just [counting the number of files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626427/how-to-count-number-of-files-and-directories-recursively-in-a-given-directory/626430#comment1932298_626430), but there were mismatches; I think sometimes certain files don't appear on both operating systems. File sizes apparently differ, too.

How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: Look into the [`cygwin`](http://www.cygwin.com/) package.  `rsync` works well on Windows under `cygwin`

Comment: @JimL. I'm getting close! `rsync -azvn --rsync-path="C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\usr\bin\rsync.exe" ssh orig_folder/* my_user@192.168.1.106:/pc_dir/*` almost works, but the last part for me to figure out is how to change the "pc_dir" part to the actual location, which looks like "K:\my_project\part1\". How am I supposed to put that in the Mac command?

Comment: I added the following line to `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`: `ChrootDirectory K:\my_project\part1` (see https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/190#issuecomment-393613390). In PowerShell, I ran `net stop sshd` and then `net start sshd`. Then, from the Mac, using SSH into the IP address of the PC proved that it landed in the correct directory. So now I need to figure out why the following isn't doing the diff properly and seems to output a list of ALL files: `rsync -azvn --rsync-path="C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\usr\bin\rsync.exe" orig_folder/* my_user@192.168.1.106:part1sub/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **Beyond Compare 4 Pro (on Windows 10)** to do this easily.

On the Mac, I enabled Remote Login. Then I used BC4Pro to compare folders:

- K:\orig_folder\part1\
- sftp://my_user@192.168.1.76/part1/

It caught that my original SCP transfer appears to have omitted a subfolder that had a name that started with an asterisk on the Mac: "*Preliminaries".

Additionally, many files called ".DS_Store" and "Icon" existed on Mac that never got copied to PC, but I think those are all OS-specific files that don't matter.

**Old attempt:**

From the Mac terminal, maybe the key is to run it like this without asterisks:

`rsync -aichzvn --rsync-path="C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\usr\bin\rsync.exe" orig_folder/ my_user@192.168.1.106:part1sub/`

(See https://serverfault.com/a/852335/119666)

...and then run it in the reverse direction too (still in the Mac terminal, but with the order of the computer folder locations switched so that the remote PC is listed before the local Mac folder).

But I couldn't get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `rsync` as a protocol for what files to copy, so it isn't OS dependent.  Some things like preserving time stamps, user/group permissions, etc. will be OS dependent though.

[Using rsync on a Mac to copy folders](https://blog.duklabs.com/using-rsync-on-mac-to-copy-files/)

[Using rsync over SSH (see #3)](https://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/)

One more tip - avoid spaces and other special characters from the remote directory, and start with your working directory being the source of the files you want to back up so you can reference it with `./` and not worry about special characters, etc. in the path on the local machine.

Personally I'd close this question out and re-ask if you still have issues using `rsync`, include your `rsync` command, etc.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/105855/74576 is showing me that I need to 1) Have rsync available to run on the Windows PC too, and 2) somehow specify its path (`C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\usr\bin\rsync.exe`) in my rsync SSH command from Mac.

Comment: See my comment up under my question; there is just one part of the command left to figure out: https://superuser.com/questions/1462861/diff-directory-contents-from-mac-to-pc-on-same-network#comment2206265_1462861

Comment: Spaces should be fine if you use the `-s` option.